# How can I see my character again after Breylna's spell practice?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did a miscellaneous quest and let Breylna Maryon, an apprentice mage, practice a spell on me at the Winterhold College. At the end of the quest my character was rendered invisible to me and only to me. I can still attack, be attacked, and be detected etc like normal but I can't even see the weapons I wield.

In my Active Effects it said something from her was supposed to wear off in 30 minutes so I figured it was no big deal and continued on questing. Well, I'm WAY far from there now (quite a few hours in hopes it would just eventually stop being dumb) and I still cannot see anything. I figure that it must be a glitch as sometimes when I reload my saved game my character will appear for just a moment. Perspective changing does nothing. Breylna provides no option for a fix. Nothing is working. Any suggestions?

Comment: you could try going back to her to complete the quest...

Comment: Does the double sexchange help you? I.e. open a console and enter `sexchange` twice.

Comment: same thing happened to me on Xbox. it has been days. and nothing has changed.

Comment: and how do you do fix this for the xbox 360 step by step i have the code but dont know how to use it

Answer (score 12):

If you are playing on the PC, open up the console by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>, type in `player.setactoralpha 100` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That should make it right again.

Comment: also got this bug after this quest. I play on ps3 so this "consol solution" isnt possible to me... Isnt there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be causing a bug

> - ◾Sometimes when she casts the first spell nothing will happen and you will be stuck waiting for it to wear off.(Nothing happens if you wait,sleep,exit and reenter or reload the last save.) Using console commands to advance the quest is the only known way to fix this.

So use the console to remove the effect, or read an elder scroll.